# Can't repartition eMMC laptop drive [HP Stream]

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

For whatever reason, the eMMC drive on my HP Stream was wiped.

All space is unallocated, and when I try to create a partition of any kind with Windows 8 or Windows 10 recovery environment, it fails.

I have tried through the GUI and also manually through diskpart.

Many times I get "Access is Denied" and a few times a "write protected" error.

On Windows 10 recovery CMD I always get: 'Data Error Cyclic Redundancy Check' Error

```
convert gpt
'Data Error Cyclic Redundancy Check' Error

create partition primary
'Data Error Cyclic Redundancy Check' Error
```

I've tried just about everything and I cannot seem to create a new partition on my newly un-allocated space.

Is my eMMC drive just crapping out?
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I would first try to to figure out exactly where the problem is. There are partition managers a lot better than diskpart; EaseUS has a great one. If that doesn't work, try running a partition manager in a non-windows enviroment. EaseUS has a bootable partition manager which may help being that its not bounded by windows.

Here is the partition manager - https://www.easeus.com/partition-manager/personal.html

Here is the bootable partition manager - https://www.easeus.com/partition-manager-guide/create-winpe-bootable-disk.html

Comment: I have examined this. There are no partitions, and partition creation fails with every software